# Are questions about spelling of geography locations on-topic?

Tags: support, status-completed, scope

Although this website appeared (initially) to be all things about Geography, after reading the help section and despite it claiming its audience is wide I think my question is not on topic: am I correct in thinking the following question is off topic here?

> I've seen 2 spellings of a place, which is correct for my given location?

The actual question is 2 fold:

> Why is there Menorca and Minorca (which is correct in Menorca and UK?
>   Why is there Addaia and Addaya (a town in Menorca) (which is correct in   Menorca and UK?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This site is about Geographic Information Systems and not general Geography so I think your question is off-topic here.

I think an answer to your question is that while there may be many incorrect spellings for the name of a location there may also be multiple correct spellings.

The reasons for there being multiple correct spellings possible will depend on the particular location being considered.